# PHP issues the error undefined offset error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to compare two MySQL tables and to drop columns of `table 2` if not in `table 1`. The code I am using is

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 


$fields = array();
$fields2 = array();
$dropcols = array();

$res=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table1");
$res2=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table2");

while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $fields[] = $x['Field'];
}

while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
    $fields2[] = $x['Field'];
}

$diff = array_diff($fields2,$fields);

$arraylen = count($diff);

for ($x=0; $x < $arraylen; $x++) {
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE table2   DROP  $diff[$x]");
}
```

Some times the code working and sometimes issue the error undefined offset 0. I don't know where the error is.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, Worked like a charm. I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: Excuseme Barmar for bothering u. Could u explain the usage of foreach(..) , $diff = array_values(..). Or Direct me to a link to study these in details if possible. Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

`array_diff` doesn't reindex the elements of the resulting array, they keep their indexes from `fields`, so there are gaps in the index. Use `foreach` to loop through the array values regardless of the indexes.

```
foreach ($diff as $column) {
    mysql_query(  "ALTER TABLE table2   DROP  $column");
}
```

Or you can do:

```
$diff = array_values(array_diff($fields2, $fields));
```

Answer (score -1):

it is becouse sometimes the array $diff will not contain any values

Comment: In that case `$arraylen` will be zero and the loop won't do anything.